# Do JDBC types actually matter?

Tags: jdbc

Can, in today's drivers, `JDBCType`s of the most popular DBMSs and set always to `JDBCType.OTHER`? Can input/output classes be used interchangeably within the character stream/binary stream/number/time point type classes?

I am asking first, specifically about `JDBCType`/`java.sql.Types` constants and, second, about the methods used for retrieving (i.e. the Java class to which the column maps). My experience with several databases was that in general, they will happily convert anything to anything else if only it makes sense. Mind you, I did not perform any kinds of exhaustive tests, it is just an experience that I could almost always access a ResultSet column as any type I wanted specifically in that context, not worrying about JDBC<=>DBMS SQL mapping. Obviously, I am not advocating here `timestamp<=>string`, `integer<=>string` conversions and similar; I am also aware for example, of the subtle differences between accessing a column as `ZonedDateTime` with `getObject`, and converting manually the result of `getTimestamp`, but that's a difference between the concepts behind these classes.

Explicitly, applications use `JDBCType` in practice only in `PreparedStatement.setNull` and `CallableStatement.registerOutParameter`, and here my experience was also that as long as I stuck to number/string/time/binary distinction I could pick the class according to wishes.

So, overall, they seem to me like a relic of questionable example from 15(?) years ago when we didn't have the experience and knowledge about building modern server side applications and most of Java EE was based on fantasies.

Comment: "*they will happily convert anything to anything else if only it makes sense*" - well the understanding of what "make sense" is quite different between different database products. While e.g. Oracle will happily run `where varchar_column = 42` Postgres will refuse to do that. While MySQL will happily run `where '1word'` all other databases will refuse to run that.

Comment: To answer "*Do the JDBC types really matter*" - if you are doing database introspection, then yes they do matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type constants themselves are also used for metadata introspection. For example, for `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns`, the result set column `DATA_TYPE` contains the `java.sql.Types` code, and `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType` returns the `java.sql.Types` code, and that applies to other metadata methods and objects. Metadata introspection might not be very important in normal programs, but it is used a lot by database tools and data access libraries or frameworks.

Other usage really depends on the driver and database system. Some drivers (and database systems) will always determine the type of columns on prepare time, and when setting values the driver will convert the value to the expected type of the parameter (as long as such a conversion is possible or specified by JDBC). That is, if the parameter is VARCHAR, and you set a long, then the driver will convert the long to string and use the string as the parameter value. For those database systems, the `java.sql.Types` and `java.sql.JDBCType` doesn't have a lot of value (beyond metadata introspection), and will usually be ignored.

In other database systems and their drivers, parameters don't necessarily have an expected type at prepare time (or the prepare phase can be skipped if the driver supplies the type information, or the database system allows you to override parameter types), and the type will be determined by explicitly setting the value (so, setting a string will determine the type as VARCHAR, while setting a long will determine the type as BIGINT, etc). In those cases the type constants will have use, for example in `setNull`, or in `setObject`, as it will specify the type of the parameter, which could infer specific conversions or behaviour on the driver or on the database. It might also be necessary for situations where a parameter is passed to a polymorphic or overloaded function (that is, the actual type of the parameters determines what the function does and what it returns).

The `registerOutParameter` in `CallableStatement` is actually a special case of that. For the first type of drivers, this is usually technically unnecessary (as the types would be determined by the prepare), while for the second type it can be either necessary, to leave conversion of values to a specific type to the database engine, or useful to be able to execute stored procedures without explicit prepare: you tell the driver which OUT types to expect, and it can then execute the procedure without having prepared it first. In that last case, on execute it will - for example - send the statement text, and the parameters and a descriptor of the OUT types expected. If there is a mismatch (incompatible types, too few or too many parameters or OUT types, etc, the database system would then reject execution, or - though I don't know if this exists in practice - the combination of actual parameter types and expected OUT types could select a specific stored procedure implementation (if a database system supports overloaded stored procedures).

Comment: Thank you, that was an informative response. I don't know though if you'll get rep for that, as someone closed the question as opinion based.

Comment: @Turin Yes, closing doesn't change that.